# Elasticsearch edgeNGram analyzer/tokenizer fuzzy query matching

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, fuzzy

We have an Accounts table that we are searching for similar records using fuzzy query with edgeNGram analyzer for multiple fields. Our setup:

**Settings**

```
{
  settings: {
    analysis: {
      analyzer: {
        edge_n_gram_analyzer: {
          tokenizer: "whitespace",
          filter: ["lowercase",  "ednge_gram_filter"]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        ednge_gram_filter: {
          type: "edgeNGram",
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
{
  mappings: {
    document_type: {
      properties: {
        uid: {
          type: "text",
          analyzer: "edge_n_gram_analyzer"
        },
        shop_name: {
          type: "text",
          analyzer: "edge_n_gram_analyzer"
        },
        seller_name: {
          type: "text",
          analyzer: "edge_n_gram_analyzer"
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
        locale_id: {
          type: "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            bool: {
              should: [
                {
                  fuzzy: {
                    uid: {
                      value: "antonline",
                      boost: 1.0,
                      fuzziness: 2,
                      prefix_length: 0,
                      max_expansions: 100
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  fuzzy: {
                    seller_name: {
                      value: "antonline",
                      boost: 1.0,
                      fuzziness: 2,
                      prefix_length: 0,
                      max_expansions: 100
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  fuzzy: {
                    shop_name: {
                      value: "antonline",
                      boost: 1.0,
                      fuzziness: 2,
                      prefix_length: 0,
                      max_expansions: 100
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        must_not: [
          {
            term: {
              locale_id: {
                value: 7
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above example finds different variations of 'antonline' string such as *"antonline", "sanjonline", "tanonline", "kotonline", "htonline", "awmonline"*. However, it doesn't match strings with punctuation like *antonline.com* or even *antonlinecom* without the dot. We tried different types of tokenizers but nothing helps.

How could we achieve the search result as we expect?

Comment: Try to use *standard* tokenizer instead of *whitespace* (in first snippet)

Comment: @marxin i tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that issue by removing everything that matches this regex:

```
[.,'\"\-+:~\^!?*\\]
```

Do the removal while building the index as well as while searching.